# how to display the current date in input field in html?

Tags: javascript, html

```js
function addDate(){
    date = new Date();
    var month = date.getMonth()+1;
    var day = date.getDate();
    var year = date.getFullYear();
    
    if (document.getElementById('date').value == ''){
        document.getElementById('date').value = day + '-' + month + '-' + year;
    }
}
```

```html
<body onload="addDate();">
        <input type="date" id="date"/>
</body>
```

it work fine when i change `type="text"` of input filed ...
but when i change `type="date"` it does not work.....

i want to display current date in type of date

thanks

Comment: <input type="date" id="date">

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="date" id="yourDatePicker" > 


document.getElementById("yourDatePicker").valueAsDate = new Date()
```

Comment: Thanks.....it works

Comment: it is displaying today 12 june....at this time in Pakistan it is 11th june.....how to fix according to country